# Python web-scraping a text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, debian

I am trying to web-scrape an HTML text from a website.

The html code:

[image]

I want to get the "Arrivals" text.
I tried with this:

```
name = soup.find("div", {'class':'m-b-m'}).text
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you meant `"label"` not `"div"`

Comment: You are searching div with class 'm-b-m'. try this name = soup.find("label", {'class':'m-b-m'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
name = soup.find("label", {'class':'m-b-m'}).text
```